# Completing all Camunda tasks in db by hand

Tags: sql, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, camunda

I am currently perf-testing a Spring-boot project that is using Camunda (nested not standalone).

In-between perf runs, the Camunda db is getting populated with tasks waiting to be executed, as expected.

When I complete the perf-test there are a handful of tasks that are left in this state. I am reusing db's between perf-test runs.

The issue that I am facing now is that when I begin a new perf-test, these pending tasks are being attempted, which is not my intention. I would like to keep the populated db, but not to poll any previous tasks.

My question is, is it possible to change all pending tasks to completed prior to starting my server? I have looked through the documentation, they seem to mainly suggest using REST calls, but I dont think that I have REST enabled in my version. Could this be done via sql before spinning up the server?

Answer (score 1):

You could register a component that is called when the engine was started and close all open tasks programatically using the java API.

kotlin code example:

```
...
@EventListener
fun onStart(evt: PostDeployEvent) {
   val taskService = evt.processEngine.taskService
   taskService.createTaskQuery().active().list().forEach { 
      taskService.complete(it.id) 
   }
}
```

Note: Depending on the process you are running, completing a task might not be enough to clear the runtime ... using the RuntimeService to cancel all running instances (`runtimeService.deleteProcessInstance`) might be another option.